# Making object sticky does not seem to work

Tags: css, sticky

I've been trying to have an image stick on the right while people can scroll the artist names on the left but maybe it's not going to work because the left side already scrolls.  Here is the page I am trying it on:

https://aarongalleries.com/test-page/

And I have position: sticky here in my css as:

```
div#hot-random_image-2 {
position: -webkit-sticky !important;
position: sticky !important;
top: 50px !important;
}
```

Thx.

Comment: In your webpage everything looks good the image is sticked to that point, Do you want that to scroll according to the artist names ?

Comment: hello , have you  tried position:fixed instead of sticky ?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question, and not your web site or any other third party site.

Comment: I did try position: fixed but that did not show still when I scrolled.  Ideally I wanted to be able to scroll through the artist names and have the image stay in place.

Comment: Ok now that is really weird. I just tried position: fixed this time just using the developer console (did not add it to the code yet) and it seems to work there. The only problem is that the footer than displays over it if I scroll too far down but is probably adjustable. I'll add it to the actual css (instead of in console) and see if it works.

Comment: Yep that worked now. Thanks for suggesting that.  It was worth trying again.  Must have been a caching issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code

```
#random-image-2 {
    width: 365px;                    /* Set proper width */
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;                 /* Add instated of sticky */
    /* top: 50px !important;  */     /* Remove this line */
}
```

Comment: I like this solution even better. The height: auto keeps the whole image in view. Thanks. That is great :)